# Shared Memory in C# concurrency

Tags: c#, concurrency

I'm trying to solve the producer-consumer concurrency problem with semaphores in c# (I believe i solved it: I believe the semaphores solves the mutual exclusion problem and at the same time it solves the sychronization problem of the two threads).
My problem is:
I don't understand why my variable "data" passed by reference (ref) in the producer instance and in the consumer instance isn't being shared in memory.
I have only been learing C# for a couple of days and I'm pretty sure I didn't understand the keyword "ref" properly. Please bear with me.
The code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ProducerConsumer
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Semaphore hasData = new Semaphore(0, 1);    //There is no data when the program starts
        Semaphore hasSpace = new Semaphore(1, 1);   //There is space to produce
        int data = 0;                               //the variable "data" will be a shared variable
        Producer producer = new Producer(hasData, hasSpace, ref data);
        Consumer consumer = new Consumer(hasData, hasSpace, ref data);
        Thread producerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(producer.Produce));
        Thread consumerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(consumer.Consume));
        producerThread.Start();
        consumerThread.Start();
    }
}
class Producer
{
    static Random rnd = new Random();
    private Semaphore hasData;
    private Semaphore hasSpace;
    private int data;
    public Producer(Semaphore hasData, Semaphore hasSpace, ref int data)
    {
        this.hasData = hasData;
        this.hasSpace = hasSpace;
        this.data = data;
    }
    public void Produce()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            hasSpace.WaitOne();
            this.data = rnd.Next(0, 100);
            Console.WriteLine("The producer made: " + this.data);
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            hasData.Release();
        }
    }
}
class Consumer
{
    private Semaphore hasData;
    private Semaphore hasSpace;
    private int data;
    public Consumer(Semaphore hasData, Semaphore hasSpace, ref int data)
    {
        this.hasData = hasData;
        this.hasSpace = hasSpace;
        this.data = data;
    }
    public void Consume()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            hasData.WaitOne();
            Console.WriteLine("The consumer got: " + this.data);
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            hasSpace.Release();
        }
    }
}
}
```

The Output:
[image]

As you can see the producer is producing in a different part of the memory and the consumer is looking at a different part of the memory.
I would also love to know how to solve this problem.
Thank you!

Comment: `this.data = data;` then your data isn't by ref anymore. it copies `data` to `this.data`

Comment: but does it only copy the value?

Comment: Is there any way for this.data to point at the same memory as the variable "data" that is being passed by reference in the constructor of the producer.

Comment: It seems like you could use `AutoResetEvent`.

Comment: I looked up the documentation. Could you please elaborate on how I can use AutoResetEvent to solve the shared memory problem?

Comment: Your consumer got always zero because you have copied original value of `ref data` to the local member `this.data`

Comment: I understand that this.data = data actually copied the value. What I actually wanted to do is to point the variable this.data to memory of the ref data. Is there a possible way to do that?

Comment: Then you need save value to the "heap" and use reference to the memory address of the saved value. In c# you can create class for this purpose. Classes are reference type, so they are is "pointers" to the memory where whole class values are. Other "dirty" way is to make your `data` variable static and global

Comment: Thank you fabio. I believe you and M.kazem Akhgary arrived to the same conclusion: Using objects as pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you pass `data` by ref its value is copied in `data` field. because `int` is a value type not a reference type.

You can use wrapper class to hold value inside reference type.

```
class RefVal<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }

    public RefVal(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

And then you have to use it instead of `int` like this this

```
RefVal<int> data = new RefVal<int>(0); //the variable "data" will be a shared variable
Producer producer = new Producer(hasData, hasSpace, data);
Consumer consumer = new Consumer(hasData, hasSpace, data);

// ...

class Producer
{
    private RefVal<int> data;

    // ...

    public Producer(Semaphore hasData, Semaphore hasSpace, RefVal<int> data)
    {
        this.hasData = hasData;
        this.hasSpace = hasSpace;
        this.data = data;
    }
    public void Produce()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            hasSpace.WaitOne();
            this.data.Value = rnd.Next(0, 100); // set value to .Value
            Console.WriteLine("The producer made: " + this.data);
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            hasData.Release();
        }
    }
}
class Consumer
{
    private Semaphore hasData;
    private Semaphore hasSpace;
    private RefVal<int> data;
    public Consumer(Semaphore hasData, Semaphore hasSpace, RefVal<int> data)
    {
        this.hasData = hasData;
        this.hasSpace = hasSpace;
        this.data = data;
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: I love the idea. I'm gonna try it. Thank you very much!